# Dynamically adding json to spacetree view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, infovis

I am using spacetree js to show the tree view.

I want to load the json on demand after clicking the node.

I have run the sample examples with hardcoded json values.

but I am not getting how to make it dynamic.....
 after selecting the node show their children and retain their parents.
I am having two problems

How to make it

1.Either reload the whole json object

2 Or add the selected childrens json to previous json object

I need the example ..
I am doing app using ruby on rails so is their any method to make customised json

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the hardcoded JSON object in the example, you could use something like [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method or [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to load JSON from remote server. Would be something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/tree/structure',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(data) {
    json = $.parseJSON(data);
  }
});
```

So in Rails, you could create a controller to return JSON response like following:

```
def treedata
  @tree = Tree.create() # object with tree structure

  respond_to do |f|
    f.json{ render :json => @tree }
  end
end
```

Hope the above helps with some idea.